# Can one improve coefficients in recursion using some machine learning algorithm?

Tags: recursion, machine-learning

I've got this prediction problem for daily data across several years. My data has both yearly and weekly seasonality.

I tried using the following recurrence:(which I just came up with, from nowhere if you like) x<sub>n</sub> = 1/4(x<sub>n-738</sub> + x<sub>n-364</sub> + x<sub>n-7</sub> + 1/6(x<sub>n-1</sub>+x<sub>n-2</sub>+x<sub>n-3</sub>+x<sub>n-4</sub>+x<sub>n-5</sub>+x<sub>n-6</sub>)

Basically, I am taking into consideration some of the previous days in the week before the day I am trying to predict and also the corresponding day a year and two years earlier. I am doing an average over them.

**My question is: can one try to improve the prediction by replacing the coefficients 1/4,1/6 etc with coefficients that would make the mean squared residual smaller?**

Comment: yes and it has been done.  RNN pretty much works like this.  your formula is missing a ).

Comment: Thanks @thang! Could you please elaborate a little bit on your comment made below? Perhaps you could tell me what I should modify in this implementation here? https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I see your problem as a regression.
If you have enough data I would run for [timeseries](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) prediction. 
You said that the data has yearly and weekly seasonality. In order to cope with that you can have two models one with weekly window and one dealing with the yearly pattern and then somehow combine them (linear combination or even another model).
However if you don't have you could try passing the above xi as features to a regression model such as linear regression,svm,feed forward neural network and on theory it will find those coefficients that produce small enough loss (error).

Comment: Hi rpet, could you please detail a little bit how the regression would be set up? Because in a regression we normally have y=Ax, while in this case my x and y's depend on each other. Thanks!

Comment: Rewrite your formula as x_n = <b, x_h> where x_h = (x_n-1,x_n-2,...).  b is the vector of parameters.  now use regression to find optimal b.  this is pretty much linear model.  you can make this model more sophisticated to improve accuracy.